# web development

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am a computer student and we wanted to develop MONOPOLY on the web...we wanted to use java as our business part...we need rich client side graphics...so we need power ful javascript code...

my question is which of the below options is better for use:

1- using libraries such a JQuery
2- develop our libraries

thanks

Comment: I don't think this can be objectively answered. As such, I'd suggest that it should be a Community Wiki at best.

Comment: @user568986 - You want to develop a Monopoly?  Didn't you learn anything from watching Microsoft's business practices.  Or perhaps you're building the oh-so famous Parker Brothers game online?  How cool!  ;)

Comment: im studying in computer faculty of tehran university and we wanted have an experience in web development...

Answer (score 4):

You do not have to develop your own JavaScript librairies. Nobody do that !! Use existing librairy like jQuery, Mootools, or Prototype !!!
When we are student, we always want to do everything, but you won't have to time to develop all your application ! Focus on your Java part !!

Comment: Agreed.  In college they make you do crazy things like write your own String class, but that's so that you can learn abstractions and understand  how to write good, reusable code.  In business, your job is to produce results using high quality, tried and tested components that can be glued together to form a high quality, revenue-generating application.

Answer (score 2):

For a project like this: don't reinvent the wheel - use jQuery, Mootools, Prototype or a similar library.

You can find a comparison chart of various JavaScript frameworks on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks).

Answer (score 2):

Always use libs around, jQuery is one of decent ones (don't forget to check all it's plugins).
Develop your own libs as the very last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the API for the various libraries such as jQuery and Prototype.  Do they provide routines that you'll use?  If so, use it.  If not, write your own library or a plugin for one of the major libraries.

Comment: you know...we thaught that if we develop our own libraries it would be a good practice, but we didn`t sure...:D

Answer (score 0):

All of the above.

Existing libraries are useful for functionality that appears in common use cases.

You are also developing an application that has scope for developing reusable components for use in other, similar, applications (i.e. other board games).

Answer (score 0):

Have look at HTML5 there is a lot of opportunities in it.

There was excellent presentation at Google I/O 2010 about that http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/

also http://plugins.jquery.com/project/html5 and http://html5gamer.com/

Comment: +1  HTML5 is bringing a lot of native functionality to the browser.  If you're building an application that may not be released to the public for some time or where your users are more hip to the latest trends, I would not suggest you discard the idea of HTML5.  It's a good idea to build your application with the future in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use JQuery.  It is becoming the standard for developing Rich Internet Applications.

Don't reinvent the wheel, but also, do not use something that may be obsolete or no longer supported in the next few years.

Take a look at these trends/insights from Google regarding some JavaScript libraries.  JQuery is increasing, while the other libraries are showing down-trends:

http://www.google.com/insights/search/#q=jquery%2Cprototype%2Cmootools%2Cdojo%2Cknockoutjs&cmpt=q